# How to Store Data from select html tag to DB and display it...Laravel

Tags: laravel

Laravel

I have 3 tables

1- users => id + name + email + password

2- categories => id + name

3- category_user => user_id + category_id

I want the users to choose their favorite categories so that only the articles for that category appear.

here the page to select category:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Category</label>
        <select name="categories[]" id="" multiple>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

how can I store this data in the category_user table? (with validate)

Also, how can I display only articles belonging to the selected categories?

Comment: You want to save multiple categories against a specific user as this name attribute implies `name="categories[]"`. It is pretty simple, loop over the $request->categories and save it against the user.

Comment: For viewing articles do you want to use eloquent or query builder?

Comment: It does not matter, it is important to solve the problem Hassan Malik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dump and die your request data in controller, you will see categories as an array. you can iterate through categories by a foreach loop and save it to category_user table. Don't forget to use current user id as user_id.

```
foreach ( $request->categories as $categoryId ) {
    CategoryUser::create( [ 'user_id' => auth()->user()->id, 'category_id' => $categoryId ] )
}
```

For display need some more information about articles table. Is one article belongs to one or many category?

Comment: I tried this solution, but I am facing a problem (Undefined type 'App \ Http \ Controllers \ CategoryUser)
Should I build Models with this name? (CategoryUser) or (Category_ User)?
Regarding your question: article belongs to many category?

Comment: Yes you can create one CategoryUser model or you can do db query to insert on that table.

Comment: Ok thank you ,and waht about display only articles belonging to the selected categories

Comment: For articles of specific categories, define model relationship and use whereHas for filtering on relation. Something like this `Article::whereHas( 'categories', function ( $q ) use ( $catIds ) { $q->whereIn('id', $catIds); })->get();`